# Get information from a JSON file and call it later

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I try to capture information from a JSON online

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.example.com/example.json', function(data) {
    var first = data.first;
    var second = data.second;
});
```

Later, at some moment, I want to call and update part of the information:

```
$("#boto").click(function() {   
    $('#check').text(first);
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="boto">boto</p>
<p id="check">check</p>
<p id="check2">check2</p>
```

I know I could put the two pieces together, perhaps when I click the button. My question is, is it possible to make the getJASON and the button separated? (The goal is to have a more clean and organized code.)

I am a beginner and I try to learn. I have made an intense search and I could not find information online. Perhaps I do not know how to search about this topic. I would appreciate any orientation. Please teach the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a global variable in your script section or in your .js file, and set the JSON data to it. Then, when you click the button, set the data using those variables. Something like this should do what you're looking for.

```
<script>

var firstData = null;
var secondData = null;

$.getJSON('https://api.example.com/example.json', function(data) {
    firstData = data.first;
    secondData = data.second;
});

$("#boto").click(function() {   
    $('#check').text(firstData);
});
```

Comment: I tried that before asking and it does not work. Try it yourself in a real case. It has 2 problems:
- It only updates the information once. You have to reload the page to get the information again
- If you do not include var firstData it makes no change. I think, It puts the text in the div check because firstData works as a global var (because it has not var in it)

Comment: This works well with a regular func. The problem here is with that getJSON

Comment: Could you call $.getJSON again from the $("#boto") function? That way when you click on the update, it also calls the getJSON and updates the variables again?

Could you put the $.getJSON in a function, then call that function whenever you need the variables to be refreshed?

Comment: I cannot put here all the things that I have tried because it would be confusing. But I tried that. The question again is that if I do what you suggest I have to put the $('#check').text(firstData); inside the getJSON. What I try is to separate the vars from putting the var in the div

Comment: I'm saying put the getJSON into it's own function, then call it in onClick or whenever else you might need to update the data. Why can't the .click function access the firstData variable? You can't separate the var from the div if you need the var to be updated each time the div is. If the var is only being updated once, then what you have is fine, but if the var needs to be updated again, you have to call that getJSON function again when the var needs to be updated.

Comment: It would be confusing to put the explanation here. So I opened another question (I do not know if that is the right way to do it?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66177218/get-information-from-a-json-and-access-to-a-var-later

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED Now I Have Added A Callback Function To Make It Easier**

You can use Ajax to do this like

````
function loadDoc(link, callback) {
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Successfully Got All Data
      let data = this.response // All Response data From The Server
      callback(data); //Giving Data To Callback Function To Run After Getting All Data
    }
  };
  ajax.open("GET", link, true);
  ajax.send();
}

loadDoc("https://www.example.com/data", function(data) {
    //Do Stuff with ```data```
})
````