# get information from a JSON and access to a var later

Tags: jquery, json

I try to capture information from a JSON online:

```
function agafar(){
$.getJSON('https://api.example.com/example.json', function(data) {
    var first = data.first;
    //$('#check').text(first); It works here
});
}
```

How can I access the var first later when I click on a button?

```
$("#boto").click(function() {
    agafar();
    //$('#check').text(first); It does not work here
 });
```

(I tried to put a global var first outside the function and first (without var) inside the function and it makes not difference)

Comment: assign it to a hidden input then get the value of hidden input later.

Answer (score 0):

That cannot work, because the fetch is asynchron. So you try to access the first variable before it is read. The perfect solution would be to return a promise from the fetch function but to make it easy to understand I will show how to do with a simple callback.

```
var first;

function agafar(Callback)
{
    $.getJSON('https://api.example.com/example.json', function(data) {
    first = data.first;
    Callback();
});

$("#boto").click(function() {   
    agafar(function()
    {  
        $('#check').text(first); It does work here
    }
});
```

In this case you can of course give first as result back and do not need the global definition of the variable.

```
function agafar(Callback)
{
    $.getJSON('https://api.example.com/example.json', function(data) {
    var first = data.first;
    Callback(first);
});

$("#boto").click(function() {   
    agafar(function(first)
    {  
        $('#check').text(first); It does work here
    }
});
```